# how to run multi fuzz test cases wirtten in one source file with go1.18?

Tags: go, fuzzing

go 1.18 has released serveral days ago.It supports fuzzing in its standard toolchain beginning in Go 1.18

but while i'm trying to write my cases , it can not run multi cases in one package(or one file?).
code:

```
package xxx
func FuzzReverse(f *testing.F) {
    testcases := []string{"Hello, world", " ", "!12345"}
    for _, tc := range testcases {
        f.Add(tc) // Use f.Add to provide a seed corpus
    }
    f.Fuzz(func(t *testing.T, orig string) {
        Reverse(orig)
    })
}

func FuzzReverse2(f *testing.F) {
    testcases := []string{"Hello, world", " ", "!12345"}
    for _, tc := range testcases {
        f.Add(tc) // Use f.Add to provide a seed corpus
    }
    f.Fuzz(func(t *testing.T, orig string) {
        Reverse(orig)
    })
}
```

and i run cmd:

```
go test  -fuzz .
```

or

```
go test  -fuzz=Fuzz
```

but the result is:

```
testing: will not fuzz, -fuzz matches more than one fuzz test: [FuzzReverse FuzzReverse2]
```

like this:
[image]

the tutorial didn't tips about it, thx for help.(my first question in stackoverflow, thx a lot!!!!)

I try to wirte multi fuzz cases in one source file,then run cmd: go test -fuzz .
expecting it work fuzz-testing,but got an error:\

> testing: will not fuzz, -fuzz matches more than one fuzz test: [FuzzReverse FuzzReverse2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all right,I've read the source of Go-fuzz module,
it's a fact that it not support multi cases for each execution.

code in :\Go\src\testing\fuzz.go

```
if len(matched) > 1 {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "testing: will not fuzz, -fuzz matches more than one fuzz test: %v\n", matched)
    return false
}
```

I hope that multi cases execution could be supported in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick-n-dirty bash script which will find all the fuzz tests in the current folder and run them for 10 seconds each:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e

fuzzTime=${1:-10}

files=$(grep -r --include='**_test.go' --files-with-matches 'func Fuzz' .)

for file in ${files}
do
    funcs=$(grep -oP 'func \K(Fuzz\w*)' $file)
    for func in ${funcs}
    do
        echo "Fuzzing $func in $file"
        parentDir=$(dirname $file)
        go test $parentDir -run=$func -fuzz=$func -fuzztime=${fuzzTime}s
    done
done
```

To use this script, create a new file named `fuzzAll.sh` and copy this code into it, then run `./fuzzAll.sh` to run all fuzz tests for 10 seconds each, or pass a different number to run for a different duration (e.g. `./fuzzAll.sh 30` to run for 30 seconds each)

For further reference, there is [an existing github issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/46312) for allowing multiple fuzz targets, but no ETA on when it will be added.